# Remove title from glossary

Tags: glossaries

I use this code:

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{glossary.tex}
\makenoidxglossaries

[...]

\subsection{Glossário}

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\printnoidxglossary
```

and had this result

[image: two muppets]
however i don't know how to remove the "3. Glossary" section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. Nobody can use this so far. But I assume, that you have to remove `numberedsection` as an option

Answer (score 2):

Remove the option `numberedsection` if the glossary title should be a numbered section but using `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={Successful foo}
}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
\subsection{Glossário} % Not needed actually

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Using `section=subsection` and `numberedsection` is probably what the O.P. requests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,section=subsection,numberedsection]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={Successful foo}
}

\begin{document}
\section{First}

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this remove only the number.

Comment: @touhami: Yes, but the question is unclear. I don't see the point to use `\subsection{Glosario` if this is done by `glossaries` already. I will update as soon as the question is improved

Comment: you're right, may be this is the point : the OP need the glossary to be subsection not a section ?

Comment: @touhami: I've provided another solution